# WebService REST com autenticação [ID, CPF, Usuário, Senha]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, restful

Olá, estou procurando pela web há um tempo mas não encontro respostas claras..

Desejo implementar um webservice rest, com tokens e etc para segurança, e o webservice consiste em apenas GET para consultas com o nosso SQL Server, mas estou tendo dificuldade em gerar uma autenticação que necessite de 4 parâmetros, que são id, cpf, usuario e senha.

Então o caminho seria o seguinte: O usuário faz login pelo App com os 4 parâmetros, bate a autenticação no servidor, gera o token que será reusado para que seja persistente o login no app e assim, poder fazer requisições GET para obter informações do seu sistema..

O projeto tem que ser em .NET 4.5 e estamos criando ele pelo Visual Studio 2015.

Alguém poderia me indicar um bom lugar para aprender sobre isso, ou dar um pouquinho dos seus minutos para me escrever uma resposta boa?

Comment: Qual é a sua dúvida em específico? O fluxo descrito parece fazer bastante sentido e não há nada de incomum em sua implementação. Dê uma olhada nesse artigo do Baltieri: https://weblogs.asp.net/andrebaltieri/implementando-bearer-autentication-com-webapi-e-owin

Comment: Eu não estou sabendo fazer um processo desse jeito com mais de 2 parâmetros (usuário, senha)

Comment: Mas isso é no processo de autorização... é só receber os parâmetros adicionais, e verificar se batem com o usuário obtido na autenticação por login e senha.

Comment: Descobri que é criando-se um objeto e recebendo com um [FromBody].

Comment: Ahhh sim, se tivesse incluído o código isso seria notado instantaneamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para registrar a minha solução, criei um model "Login" que continha todas as informações necessárias para a chamada no meu Controller com o parâmetro FromBody.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]Login param)
{
    //TODO
}
```

A partir daí, todas as requisições de POST ao WebApi seriam complementadas com os parâmetros (Json) ao model Login, podendo então usar todos os campos necessários para meus métodos.